# d3.js grouped bar chart with multi-dimensional data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create grouped bar chart in d3.js v5 but stuck on iterating my multi-dimensional data. And unfortunately I didn't find any example for my needs.
My data:

```
var data = [
    {country:'country1', industry:'industry1', parameter:'parameter1', year:2001, value:111},
    {country:'country1', industry:'industry2', parameter:'parameter1', year:2001, value:121},
    {country:'country1', industry:'industry3', parameter:'parameter1', year:2001, value:131},
    {country:'country2', industry:'industry1', parameter:'parameter1', year:2001, value:211},
    {country:'country2', industry:'industry2', parameter:'parameter1', year:2001, value:221},
    {country:'country2', industry:'industry3', parameter:'parameter1', year:2001, value:231},

    {country:'country1', industry:'industry1', parameter:'parameter1', year:2002, value:111},
    {country:'country1', industry:'industry2', parameter:'parameter1', year:2002, value:121},
    {country:'country1', industry:'industry3', parameter:'parameter1', year:2002, value:131},
    {country:'country2', industry:'industry1', parameter:'parameter1', year:2002, value:211},
    {country:'country2', industry:'industry2', parameter:'parameter1', year:2002, value:221},
    {country:'country2', industry:'industry3', parameter:'parameter1', year:2002, value:231},

    {country:'country1', industry:'industry1', parameter:'parameter1', year:2003, value:111},
    {country:'country1', industry:'industry2', parameter:'parameter1', year:2003, value:121},
    {country:'country1', industry:'industry3', parameter:'parameter1', year:2003, value:131},
    {country:'country2', industry:'industry1', parameter:'parameter1', year:2003, value:211},
    {country:'country2', industry:'industry2', parameter:'parameter1', year:2003, value:221},
    {country:'country2', industry:'industry3', parameter:'parameter1', year:2003, value:231}
];
```

Result I expecting: years 2001, 2002, 2003 on axis X. For every year 6 bars - all pairs contry-industry.

So I make subgroups, svg, axis - it's all good:

```
let subgroups = ['country', 'industry'];
let margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30};
let width = 600;
let height = 400;

let svg = d3.select("#mychart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

let xBar = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }))
            .rangeRound([0, width])
            .padding([0.2]);
svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xBar));
let yBar = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.value; })])
            .rangeRound([ height, 0 ]);
svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yBar));

let xBarSubgroup = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(subgroups)
            .range([0, xBar.bandwidth()])
            .padding([0.05]);
```

But the visible result is only 1 bar for each year: all 6 bars are in one place:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + xBar(d.year) + ",0)";
            })
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d) {
                return subgroups.map(function(key) {
                    return {key: d[key], value: d.value};
                });
            })
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return xBarSubgroup(d.key); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return yBar(d.value); })
            .attr("width", xBarSubgroup.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return height - yBar(d.value);
            });
```

Here's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3agybv4/27/)

Possibly I missed thansform somewhere, and also need to set width of bars.
Please help?!